# Python Django, Convert Image object to File object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, image, backend

So basically i am trying to convert PIL Image object to File object so Django can process it, this is what I have tried so far in views.py:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    title = request.POST.get('title','')
    fil = request.FILES.get('fil')
    img=Image.open(fil)
    img = img.resize((500,500))
    img_bytes=io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_bytes, format='PNG')
    img = io.TextIOWrapper(img_bytes)
    pt = Pt.objects.create(title=title,fil=img)
```

Basically this will return an error when trying to upload an image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pass an [`ImageFile` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/#the-imagefile-class) to the `ImageField` instead, which can be instantiated using your binary stream `img_bytes` and the filename of the original file attached in the POST request:

```py
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

...

img = ImageFile(img_bytes, name=fil.name)
pt = Pt.objects.create(title=title, fil=img)
```

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/#the-file-class):

> The [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File) class is a thin wrapper around a Python [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) with some
> Django-specific additions. Internally, Django uses this class when it
> needs to represent a file.
>
> Django provides a built-in class specifically for images. [`django.core.files.images.ImageFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.images.ImageFile) inherits all the attributes and
> methods of [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File), and additionally provides the following:
>
> **width** Width of the image in pixels.
>
> **height** Height of the image in pixels.

Comment: What is `File` exactly? i know the existence of `file` only, which is used for files operations